# unable to log in to Linux server with ssh

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I have a server with real IP Addresses connected to my office network.
once I change the server IP address to a different IP (10.0.0.100) and connect my laptop to it
I'm unable to connect to it with ssh.
this is the message I get:
$ error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use'

I can ping 10.0.0.100 with no problem and it also aksed me to enter a username and password but I can not login and I see on my ssh client "password not correct"
$ error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed:' Address already in use - I see on the server side
any idea?
Thanks!!
Elad.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run two copies of ssh on the same port or something?  What do you see when you run `ss -lpn`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like two different problems to me. "password not correct" is a mostly meaningless answer (and it is often not true). Start your `sshd` in debug-mode to see the real reason why it fails.